# Representability of matroids over finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

I have several questions regarding representability of matroids.

**Question 1.** Does there exist a finite matroid that is representable over an infinite field, but is not representable over any finite field?

**Question 2.** Does there exist a finite matroid that is representable over a field of characteristic $0$, but is not representable over any field of positive characteristic?

**Question 3.** Does there exist a finite matroid that is representable over a field of characteristic $0$, but $\{\mathrm{char}(F): M \text{ is representable over }F\}$ is a finite set?

I care about Question 1 most, and find other quetions also interesting. I briefly checked Oxley, Matroid theory but did not find an answer.

Comment: I think the answer to all three questions is no, by a spreading out argument.

Comment: The answer to Q2 and Q3 is no, by considering possibilities of the [characteristic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_representation#Characteristic_set).

Comment: Since linear representability of a given finite matroid over a field $F$ is a property of $F$ expressible in first-order logic, negative answers to Questions 2 and 3 follow from the compactness theorem of first-order logic. Then the completeness of the theory of algebraically closed fields of any fixed characteristic implies that a finite matroid representable over a field $F$ (and thus over its algebraic closure) is also representable over the algebraic closure of the prime field of the same characteristic. A negative answer to Q1 then follows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main results of Rado's [Note on Independence Functions](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/plms/s3-7.1.300) settle all three questions. The first few lines of [Effective Versions of Two Theorems of Rado](http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/%7Emayhew/Publications/BFKM.pdf) give a perfect recap of those results, so here they are verbatim:

> Our starting point is given by the following two theorems of Rado [5].
>
> **Theorem 1** (Rado, 1957). Let $M$ be a matroid representable over a field $K$. Then $M$ is representable over a simple algebraic extension of the prime field of $K$.
>
> **Theorem 2** (Rado, 1957). Let $K$ be an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $N$ , and let $M$ be a matroid representable over $K$. Then there is a positive integer $c$ such that given any prime $p > c$ there is a positive integer $k = k(p) ≤ N$ such that $M$ is representable over $GF(p^k)$. For infinitely many $p$, $k(p) = 1$.
>
> Together, these two theorems say that if a matroid is linearly representable, then it is representable over a finite field.